# Finding goal in ext4 file system

Tags: linux-kernel, ext4, extent

The file extents.c (fs/ext4/extents.c) in linux kernel 4.7.2 deals with file allocation methods.

ar.goal is calculated by a function ext4_ext_find_goal

```
ar.goal = ext4_ext_find_goal(inode, path, map->m_lblk);
```

Can anyone please explain how this function works ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ext4_ext_find_goal()` is called when we need to allocate new block.

In [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/ext4/extents.c#L4442), this function is called as you said.

```
ar.goal = ext4_ext_find_goal(inode, path, map->m_lblk);
```

In this context, `path` is not NULL. So, `ext4_ext_find_goal()` will find block number of that `path`, and return this block number.